# Use VBA to detect if a Excel is displaying the "Enable Content" security warning

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am looking for VBA code to check and see if the Security Warning "Enable Content" is being displayed on my user's screen. Due to the environment I work in I cannot just turn it off.

We are using Excel 2013.

Comment: Refresh my memory — under what circumstance does the ‘‘Enable Content’’ security warning appear?

Answer (score 0):

*This VBA code will help you to determine whether Macro is Enable or Disable.*

If is Disabled then you get the Message in Cell A2 **Enable the Macro** otherwise Excel suggest you that **Macro is Enable**.

**NB:** To find the settings all about the MACRO as you know through the **File Menu** one could reach to *Option, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Macro Settings.*

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

      If Excel.Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow Then
       Sheet1.Range("A2") = "Enable the Macro"
      Else
       Sheet1.Range("A2") = "Macro is Enabled !!"
      End If

   End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: this works great for the "Enable Macros", now i am looking for the same type of help with "Enable Contents" message that keeps coming up.  For the record this is happening after the on open macros have run.

Comment: @Chris, nice to hear from you and happy to learn that it's working for you,, then first Vote it as Answer.

Comment: Soon I'll upload the VBA for Enable Content.