# VBA Add-In Halts When Adding Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

**The problem**

I have written an Excel VBA add-in that is contained in a .xlam file. When it runs, it adds a new tab to the spreadsheet. This tab is then filled with all of its output.

If I open a spreadsheet I have received from an e-mail, I get a yellow bar that says "SECURITY WARNING Macros have been disabled." (I am using Excel 2013)
[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skaq7.png)

When I run my VBA add-in, it runs without complaint. It creates a new sheet, *but then halts completely with no error messages*. The yellow security warning bar disappears, and if I run the add-in again it runs normally.

Here is the code around where it halts:

```VB
Debug.Print "Sheet was not found" ' <- I see this message when I open the VBA Editor '
Dim WS As Worksheet
On Error GoTo SheetErr ' <- This does not happen, I would see a message if it did '
Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)) ' <- A new sheet is added, but program halts execution here with no messages '
Debug.Print "Sheet was created" ' <- I do not see this message when I open the VBA Editor '
```

**Solution I'm looking for**

I am looking for a way to know if that yellow bar is present (and macros are disabled), so I can avoid this whole issue.

I am also just curious about this behavior where VBA just stops without an error message. I would expect either:

1. The add-in does not run at all, because Macros are disabled, or
2. When I try to add a sheet, I get an error message

**Things I have tried**

1. [Use VBA to detect if a Excel is displaying the "Enable Content" security warning](https://superuser.com/questions/1290405/use-vba-to-detect-if-a-excel-is-displaying-the-enable-content-security-warning) But

```VB
Application.AutomationSecurity
```

is always 1, regardless of whether I see the warning bar.

2. My VBA project is signed, and I made myself a trusted publisher with the same certificate. This had no effect
3. I have had this problem with Excel 2013 and Excel 2010, but not with Office 365. To me this implies that it's a bug in Excel that Microsoft has fixed.

Anyone have any ideas? Or seen this before? Thanks much.

**SOLUTION**

Ok, I figured out a solution. I set a handler sub to be called in right before I try to create the sheet. If the sheet is created successfully, the call is cancelled. If not, the handler is called, and it shows a nice message to the user about what happened.

```VB
Application.OnTime macrosDisabledBugTime, macrosDisabledBugCall

Dim WS As Worksheet
On Error GoTo SheetErr
Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
On Error GoTo 0

Application.OnTime earliesttime:=macrosDisabledBugTime, procedure:=macrosDisabledBugCall, schedule:=False
```